# Java JMenu CTRL+C shortcut not working

Tags: java, swing, hotkeys, jmenu

I'm trying to use `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+X` and `Ctrl+V` as Swing `JMenu` shortcut using NetBeans Visual Designer in my app. All of other shortcuts work except these.

What's the problem?

Comment: If my assumption happened to be true and you're stuck, I can give you code example how to remove these bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Those Key Bindings are used by default for text components. So if focus is on a text component they will invoke the default Action for the text component.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to guess what the problem is from your description, but let me guess: do you happen to have JTextArea on the same JFrame? It has some neat property called actionMap (setActionMap(), getActionMap()), which probably has these Accelerators registered.

Comment: wrong: it's not the actionMap which contains the keyBindings (aka: accelerators) but the inputMap.